# Android Fragment Update TextView From AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that uses HttpGet to fetch content from a remote server. I have tested and this is working fine, now I want to update a TextView with the result of this AsyncTask. Here is what I have done.

From the OnCreateView of the Fragment, I get reference to a Button and a TextView, I initially hide the TextView and then in the OnClickListener for the button I want to unhide the textview and update that textview with the result of my AsyncTask

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_programs_list, container, false);
        Button btnLoadPrograms = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLoadPrograms);
        TextView tvShowPrograms = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvRestCall);
        tvShowPrograms.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnLoadPrograms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startNewAsyncTask();    

            }
        });

        return rootView;
```

Now in the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask, I want to update the Textview

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            getView().findViewById(R.id.tvRestCall).setVisibility(View.SHOW); //Does not exit
        }
```

How do I get a reference to the TextView from within the AsyncTask in a Fragment and then update that TextView with the result of the doinbackground.

Comment: You can pass the text view reference to startNewAsyncTask() and then pass it on to your actual AsyncTask in constructor and use that in onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use `getView().findViewById(R.id.tvRestCall).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvShowPrograms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and is a good option, I ended up setting a public property for the TextView so It is accessible from the OnPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113949/ksarmalkar - you can send a reference to AsyncTask and then use this reference to set Visibility  by `mYourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue as follows
Set a public property for the textView

```
public TextView tvShowPrograms;
```

Then in OnCreateView I initialize the TextView and set the text to null

```
tvShowPrograms = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvRestCall);
        tvShowPrograms.setText("");
```

And then the onPostExecute, I simply set the textView to the result.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tvShowPrograms.setText(result);
        }
```

Thanks for the answers, I am glad it is working